# 'Microsoft Exchange Server' reported error (0x8004011B)

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2003

**Unknown error 0x8004011B** appears after an Outlook Send and Receive operation.

Exchange Server 2007, clients Outlook 2003

[image: error_image]

I looked at these with no luck so far. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555049
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922255 (editing registry, dismount and mount didn't help.)

It has something to do with the Offline Address List, the Global Address List doesn't update. 
EDIT: 
**oabinteg.exe /s:mailserver /t:storealtest /v:2 /l**
Failure: ADsOpenObject
ADSI Error: hr = 0x8007203a - LDAP_SERVER_DOWN - ERROR_DS_SERVER_DOWN: Cannot co
ntact the LDAP server.
Function: HrGetRootDSEData
Line number: 177
**oabinteg.exe /s:mailserver /t:oabfldcheck /v:2 /l**
Opening the Exchange Public Folder Store.
Retrieving the message store table.
Obtaining store table properties.
WARNING: Unable to read properties from the store table.
Property not set or not found for Property Tag = 0x6633000A, PR_HIERARCHY_SERVER
Store Offline: 1 (1 = True | 0 = False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error code pop up on only one station, i noticed on the net that it probably has something to do with the .oab files, so i erased all the .oab files from the "C:\Documents and Settings\USER ACCOUNT\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook" folder and did a new send\recieve that reinstated them and now all is well.

I dont really know if that messed anything up yet, but nothing pops out.
This was a workaround to messing with the registry to do that same thing.

In any way, now the error is gone.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening to all your clients, just one, or a select few?

What antivirus/firewall software are you running on the server? The clients? Have you disabled it on both and tested again?

Following the instructions in your second link (MS KB 922255) to enable diagnostic logging, what events are posted in the server's event log when this failed?

Comment: It's happening to all clients. I disabled antivirus/firewall and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

ahhh, offline address book troubleshooting! What fun. Try the troubleshooting steps [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dgoldman/archive/2006/10/23/outlook-client-fails-to-download-the-oab-with-error-0x8004011b.aspx) and post the results.